# Openlayers map not resizing correctly on initial load. Resizes fine after manual browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, openlayers-3

I have a fairly basic openlayers (version 3.7.0) map embedded in an HTML page created using the dojo toolkit (verions 1.10.4). All components load, however the initial map is stretched. When the browser window is resized, the map resizes correctly and the stretching issue disappears. It appears as though this is happening because the map gets loaded before the various HTML elements are done rendering/resizing. I'm a CSS newbie, so I'm not 100% sure.

Below are two screenshots, one showing how the map appears when it first loads, the second shown the result after manually resizing the browser slightly.

*Stretched Map*
[image: Stretched Map on Initial Load]
*Correct Map Display After Manual Browser Resize*
[image: Map displays correctly after manual browser window resize]

The live application can be accessed [here](http://cvwdgis.org/apps/historical.html).

The CSS for the application can be accessed [here](http://cvwdgis.org/apps/css/historical.css).

The javascript for the map can be found [here](http://cvwdgis.org/apps/js/historical.js).

Answer (score 0):

Go the same problem on twitter-bootstrap and responsive full width/height maps. You could try to use [map.updateSize()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#updateSize) or [map.setSize()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#setSize)

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        map.updateSize();
    }, 200);
```

Maybe it helps. For me it didn't so i used jquery `$(window).height();` to add the correct height for the map-container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it may be that the map's trying to render before DOMContent has finished loading. Creating the map after DOMContentLoaded has been emitted fixed the issue for us on OpenLayers 3.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var map = new ol.Map({
  // ...
});
```